# How can I create an instance of class dynamically in python

Tags: python-3.x, class, object, instance

I am trying to create a library management software.
I want to dynamically create an instance of class Library.

```
class Library(object):

  def __init__(self,name,book_list):
      self.name = name
      self.book_list = book_list

  def lend(self,book,stdname):
      if book in self.book_list:
          print(f"Book name: {book} lend to {stdname}")
          self.book_list.remove(book)
      else:
          print(f"Book name: {book} not present currently")

  def accept(self,book):
      print(f"Thanks for using our services")
      self.book_list.append(book)

class Student(Library):

  def __init__(self,name,due):
      self.name = name
      self.due = due

  def borrow(self,book_name):
      if self.due == 0:
          libname = input("Enter the name of library from which book has to be given: ")
          if libname in globals():
              globals()[libname].lend(book_name,self.name)
              self.due+=1
          else:
              print(f"Sorry {libname} is not regeistered with our system")
      else:
        print("Sorry you have already borrowed a book from us")

  def returnBook(self,book_name):
      if self.due == 1:
          libname = input("Enter the name of library form which book was given: ")
          if libname in globals():
              globals()[libname].accept(book_name)
              self.due -=1
          else:
              print(f"Sorry {libname} is not regeistered with our system")
      else:
          print("OOPS we dont have any book given to you currently!")



while True:
  command = input("Enter you Command here:")

  if command.upper() == "/REGISTER":
      libname = input("Enter the name of library: ") #can be say Books
      libviewname = input("Enter the viewname of library: ") #must be lib1
      booklist = eval(input("Enter the book_list: ")) # a list conatining some books as string can be ["Booka","Bookb","Bookc"]
      #here i want to create an instance of class Library like: libviewname = Library(libname,booklist)


  elif command.upper() == "/REGISTER_STD":
      stdname = input("Enter the name of student :")
      stdviewname = input("Enter the viewname of student: ")
      dueinfo = int(input("Enter amount of due: "))
      stdviewname.Student(stdname,stdviewname)
```

well the code is not complete. Here when user enter /register then he/she will have to provide 3 things. 1. Name of library
2. Identifier for instance
3. List of book available

when given then i want to make a instance like
identifier = Library(Name of library,List of books)

For example if i get following values:

libviewname = "lib1"

libname = "Libraryworld"

booklist = ["Book_A","Book_B"]

then i want to pass it like:

lib1 = Library(libname,booklist)

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a custom variable for the library, store it in a dictionary as a key/value pair:

```
libs = {}
libs[libviewname] = Library(libname,booklist)
```

You don't want to store it in `globals()`.  What if the user entered `Library` and you stored it in the global namespace?  It would overwrite your Library class!